# Suprime .svc in URL of WCF-C#

Tags: wcf

I start to work with WCF - C#, because I need to make a big scale project, and I found the follow problem:
I have tried to erase in the URL of a service WCF the .svc extension with following code:

```
using System.Web;    
namespace PruebaWCFEndpoint
{
    public class RemoveSvc : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += delegate
            {

                HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
                string path = ctx.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
                path = path.Replace("Hola.svc", "Hola");
                ctx.RewritePath(path, null, ctx.Request.QueryString.ToString(), false);
            };

        }
    }
}
```

and the following code is the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <!--
        The follow line was added by myself *************
      -->
      <add name ="removesvc" type="PruebaWCFEndpoint.RemoveSvc,PruebaWCFEndpoint"/>
      <!--
      ******************************
      -->
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

But I am tring to test and the "WCF Test client" tool show the following message:

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:9086/Hola.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error URI: http://localhost:9086/Hola.svc Los metadatos contienen una referencia que no se puede resolver: 'http://localhost:9086/Hola.svc'. El tipo de contenido text/html; charset=utf-8 del mensaje de respuesta no coincide con el tipo de contenido del enlace (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). Si usa un codificador personalizado, aseg£rese de que el m‚todo IsContentTypeSupported se implemente correctamente. Los primeros 1024 bytes de la respuesta fueron: ' 
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
```

The service interface is the follow:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace PruebaWCFEndpoint
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHola
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string saludar(string nombre);
    }
}
```

and their implementation is the follow:

```
namespace PruebaWCFEndpoint
{
    public class Hola : IHola
    {
        public string saludar(string nombre)
        {
            return "hola" + nombre;
        }
    }
}
```